# where to store chat threads , for better performance and easier management?

Tags: c#, xml, database, model-view-controller, chat

I am building a chat feature in an asp.net mvc website ,something like stackoverflow chat.

I have a table in the db for users and chat groups.

My question is where to save these info:

- Chat history 'which needs to be cleared every 3 days'.
- users status 'went online, offline or away'.
- A user is currently writing a message...

And some more info like these which change very fast while many users are chatting .
Is it fine to keep all these data in the same website db? Or should I create different tables away from the users table ? Or should I go with XML files?
If XML files is your choice, can you tell me a hint about how to organize the created XML files and how they will look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stay away from files, mainly because it is very hard to manage file concurrency when dealing with multiple updaters (which you may have if you have, say, load-balanced web servers).

A database is a good idea, depending on your scale (relational databases on good hardware scale to hundreds if not thousands of simultaneous updaters, but often fall off a cliff after that).  If you are not expecting to have hundreds of simultaneous users, a database with clients using AJAX polling or [Comet connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) is probably the right way to go.  And don't discount the fact that almost every programmer you might hire knows how to work with a database.

Other options you might look at are message queues, whereby each client has a server-side message queue that is periodically checked, again using using AJAX polling or [Comet connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).  Queues are nice because you don't need to keep track of which messages the client already saw- you just take whatever is there off of the queue.  Queues with [topic support](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html) also make a nice way to build a stateful online/offline status.

Finally, some NoSQL databases ([CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)) provide very good scaling by sharding across multiple machines, and they store hierarchical data like an XML file would (they actually use JSON to store their data), so a conversation thread would be a natural fit there.